# Mongodb river performance

Tags: elasticsearch

In *Fetching data from other systems: river* section of **Elasticsearch server** book, the author wrote:

> Please consider that when using a river, you are bound to the
>   performance of a single node. So for heavy processing of documents, a
>   standalone indexing application is preferred.

I'm not sure what *standalone indexing application* means in this context? Does it mean we need to implement our own application that pull out data from our database and save it to ES? Or an other way is for each time we save a record in a table that will be using for searching, we also need to save it to ES?

P/S: I could not find any information regarding this performance issue in Elastic server official documentation for rivers. Where can I find the document related the above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely do the later.
It will help you to have near real time search for a minimal cost.

You can also add in the middle a message Queue System like RabbitMQ.

My 2 cents.